# in a hurry and in haste

Tags: phrases

I understand these phrases have basically the same meaning. If so, why does the former have an indefinite article and latter no article? Any logical explanation?

Comment: Sure. _Hurry_ is an event noun and therefore countable, so it gets an indefinite article. _Haste_, on the other hand, is a abstract state noun and therefore uncountable, so it gets no article.

Answer (score 1):

[*In haste*](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=byte&byte=73084139&egdisplay=open&egs=73102387) does not generally take the indefinite article because it was borrowed directly from Old French *en haste* (ModFr *en hâte*), the preposition varying in Middle English among *in, an,* or *on*.

*Hurry*, however, as verb or noun, is first attested in Shakespeare:

> His remedies are tame i’ the present peace
>   And quietness of the people, which before
>   Were [*in wild hurry*](https://www.opensourceshakespeare.org/views/plays/play_view.php?WorkID=coriolanus&Act=4&Scene=6&Scope=scene). — *Corialanus* 4.6.

While Shakespeare used no article, *in a [state of] x* is a common pattern in English: *in a rush, lather, dither, rage,* etc. Curiously enough, the article does not make the noun denoting that state countable. If you were in a hurry yesterday morning and again in the afternoon, you weren’t **in hurries* yesterday.

> and being soone after aduertised of the proclamation, he came forth *in a hurry*: — Francis Bacon, *A declaration of the practises & treasons attempted and committed by Robert late Earle of Essex*, 1601. EEBO
>
> Could Laureate Dryden Pimp and Fry’r engage, 
>   Yet neither Charles nor James be [*in a rage*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uc1.31822043035328;view=1up;seq=81;skin=mobile)? — Alexander Pope, “Satire I, Imitations of Horace,”  *Works of Alexander Pope, Esq.*, vol. IV, London, 1751, 67.
>
> … smoothing discords which would have left your man of affairs [*in a dither*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uc1.b3760021;view=1up;seq=162;skin=mobile) … — H. J. Massingham, *The friend of Shelley; a memoir of Edward John Trelawny*, New York, 1930.

*In a haste* arose to conform to this pattern:

> whan men doo thynges *in a haste* … — Gulielmus Gnaphaeus, John Palsgrave, trans., *The comedye of Acolastus translated into oure englysshe tongue*, 1540. EEBO
>
> Would not a iuſt ſovereign rather deify theſe, knowing who are the beſt of men, and not ſhut heaven [*in a haſte*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=osu.32435021346473;view=1up;seq=32;skin=mobile) … — Robert Millar, *The History of the Propagation of Christianity and Overthrow of Paganism*, London, 1731, 24.

To judge by a Google search, the most frequent use of *in a haste* occurs today among speakers in India, Africa, and in International English, though there are still a few American and British writers who favor it.

> As the conflict rages, indications are that the National Assembly may not be [*in a haste*](https://books.google.de/books?id=_nQuAQAAIAAJ&q=%22in+a+haste%22&dq=%22in+a+haste%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjSoJH1-anfAhXDfFAKHb9hCVUQ6AEIOzAE) to look into the matter. — *Newswatch: Nigeria's Weekly Magazine*, 2006.
>
> Sir, today, if we do anything [*in a haste*](https://books.google.de/books?id=OQkNAQAAMAAJ&q=%22in+a+haste%22&dq=%22in+a+haste%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjSoJH1-anfAhXDfFAKHb9hCVUQ6AEIPzAF), again and again, I am saying, if we just go around *in a haste* without getting these credentials and facts and figures, it would not stand in a court of law. — Parliament of India, 2006.

Answer (score 0):

According to Merriam-Webster's Dictionary:
HASTE -
rash or headlong action :
She sent the letter in haste and later regretted it.

IN A HURRY -
without delay : 
as rapidly as possible:
the police got there in a hurry.

But nowadays it is possible to use 'in a haste' as well.
One of  numerous examples from Reverso.context.net:
'I wish I could bring you a picture, but I was in a haste'.